# Scala function that takes dynamic class as parameter

Tags: scala, generics, sttp

Alrighty, a realtime example of what I'm trying to do. I am using [Scala Sttp](https://sttp.softwaremill.com/en/latest/) as my Http Client. I have bunch of requests, so I wanted to make it more abstract. I wanted to generalise all `get` requests under abstract function that would look something like:

```
  def getRequest(
    uri: String,
    queryString: String,
    responseClass: **ANYCLASS**, --> I am unsure how to do this
    trackingId: String,
    component: String = "http-v2-client-get-request",
    numberOfRetries: Int = 0
  ): Either[HttpErrorInfo, **ANYCLASS**] = {

    val request = basicRequest
      .get(uri"$uri")
      .response(asJson[responseClass])
  }
  ...
```

So my question is how to replace `responseClass` signature so I can provide any `case class` so it gets mapped correctly.

Sorry if my question is somewhat bad, I am new to Scala and still learning how to dynamically do things

Comment: `def getRequest[T](...): Either[HttpErrorInfo, T] = ...` and `asJson[T]`?

Comment: This runs into

`No implicits found for parameter evidence$1: Decoder[T]`

There are so many decoders to import from circe unsure which one is the best after that

Comment: The answer is a typeclass, in this case it already exists `Decoder`, check this: https://gist.github.com/BalmungSan/c19557030181c0dc36533f3de7d7abf4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```scala
  def getRequest[T: Decoder](
    uri: String,
    queryString: String,
    trackingId: String,
    component: String = "http-v2-client-get-request",
    numberOfRetries: Int = 0
  ): Either[HttpErrorInfo, T] = {

    val request = basicRequest
      .get(uri"$uri")
      .response(asJson[T])
  }
  ...
```

Please notice the context bound `: Decoder`.